# PHP - RethinkDB giving me "Failed to load:" error

Tags: php, rethinkdb

**UPDATE: Okay, so the issue is the \r\epochTime(),
When I remove this, it works fine without errors.
Any ideas?**

I switched to rethinkdb about a month ago now and have a project currently running, using it just fine.

**UPDATE: When selecting from the database, it shows no errors. Only when inserting.**

I am in the process of setting up a new project on a new vps, and decided to use rethinkdb again as it can hold alot of data.

My issue is, It keeps showing me an annoying message whenever I insert, grab or delete data.
It shows me "Failed to load: (then whatever I tried searching or inserting)"

- e.g. > [33mFailed to load: /var/www/html/backend/app/App/0xb3fec39fb5b5b39eeeacdfb0a2aca6cc866d5a48.php

[Take a look at the image here of the error it's showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9itF.png)

I checked my config file for rethinkdb and everything seems to be fine.

I also gave rethinkdb permission for the web files.

I also checked the rethinkdb log file, and no errors are showing there...

NEW: I just also deleted the rethinkdb_data folder to start fresh then restarted retrhinkdb but still getting the same message... Failed to load:

My rethinkdb data directory is located as /var/www/html/rethinkdb_data/

I'm not sure why it's trying to even go inside the /var/www/html/backend/app/App/?

It's picking my brain alot as I cannot find any documentation or error for the issue I am having.

Does anything know anything about my issue?

**UPDATE WITH MY CODE:**
(So my code is an api system)

**The first file that receives the incoming data (index.php):**

```
// Adding a new ETHEREUM address
$app->get('/newaccount', function (Request $request, Response $response) use ($ethApi, $accounts) {

$callbackUrl = '';
$destinatioAddress = '';

try {
    // Call EthApi function to make new account
    $password = randomPassword();
    $newAccount = $ethApi->newAccount($password);

    if (!empty($newAccount) || $newAccount !== null) {
        // Good, new account was created, insert into databse and return the data
        // Now insert into database

        $data = [
            'account' => $newAccount,
            'callback_url' => $callbackUrl,
            'destination_address' => $destinatioAddress,
            'dateCreated' => \r\epochTime(time()),
            'identifier' => randomIdentifier(),
            'pass' => hashString($password),
        ];

        // Insert the account
        $accounts->insert($data);

        // Return their account address
        $response->withStatus(200);
        $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        $message['ok'] = $newAccount;
        return $response->withJson($message);

    } else {
        $response->withStatus(500);
        $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        $error['err'] = 'Could not generate a new address';
        return $response->withJson($error);
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $response->withStatus(500);
    $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    $error['err'] = $e->getMessage();
    return $response->withJson($error);
}
});
```

**Then the code that inserts into the database:**
(the  $accounts->insert($data) function)

```
// Insert into accounts
public function insert($data) {
  \r\table("accounts")
    ->insert($data)
    ->run($this->conn);
}
```

This is literally all I'm using other than the function to create the eth address's too, but it returns an address fine in a string format...

**You can see in the image below, that the data is getting inserted fine:**
[Check the image of the database here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcuEH.png)

Comment: Just a guess, but thats obviously not a file name you would dream up. Is that a cached PHP file, maybe try purging the cache

Comment: You should show us any part of code that causes the error, definitely it tries to show you a yellow text using ANSI coloring codes, but I'm not sure if it's effect or cause

Comment: @RiggsFolly No i do not have a file named that. I just checked cache, I don't even have apcu_clear_cache() function installed. I also just did a graceful restart on apache... still showing that error.

Comment: @biesior I will post my code now.

Comment: `0xb3fec39fb5...` - the missing file name is also in your DB in the `account` column, have no idea, why and what it does, anyway isn't your logic trying to access that file dynamically somehow? I'm afraid, you need to spend more time analyzing and debugging your code.

Comment: @biesior Please check the update at the very top. It was the epochTime() causing the issue. But I define the php rethinkdb class in the index.php so it should still be able to use it

Comment: It appears that none of the time functions are working....
\r\epoch() doesn't work, \r\now() doesn't work... I guess I'll have to just enter a string for the date as a work around. Really strange as it works on my other vps.